# How hide header on iOS 13 Collection View Compositional Layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios13, uicollectionviewlayout

I encounter a wonder point when deploy the iOS 13 Compositional Layout.

I want to hide collection view header and implement `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` method, however the `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` can not work on Compositional Layout

This my Compositional Layout:

```
lazy var collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout = {
    // item layout deploy
    let cellItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.2))
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.33), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let cellItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: cellItemSize)
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    cellItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 4, leading: 4, bottom: 4, trailing: 4)
    item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 4, leading: 4, bottom: 4, trailing: 4)

    // group layout deploy
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),  heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.2))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 3)
    let containerGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),  heightDimension: .absolute(215))
    let containerGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: containerGroupSize, subitems: [cellItem, group, group, group, group])

    // section layout deploy
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: containerGroup)
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 4, leading: 0, bottom: 4, trailing: 0)

    // Headers layout deploy
    let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(18))
    let header = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerSize, elementKind: SupplementaryViewOfKind.Header.rawValue, alignment: .top)
    section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [header]

    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)

    return layout
}()
```

Implement `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    guard
        kind == SupplementaryViewOfKind.Header.rawValue,
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: XXXHeader.identifier, for: indexPath) as? XXXHeader
        else { return UICollectionReusableView() }
    if isFullScreen {
        // customer header with titleLabel property
        header.titleLabel.text = segmentedControl.titleForSegment(at: indexPath.section)
    } else {
        header.titleLabel.text = nil
    }
}
```

Then I tried into `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` but could't work

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    if isFullScreen {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 18)
    } else {
        return CGSize.zero
    }
}
```

Is there any idea or new way to hide Compositional Layout header.

Answer (score 3):

When you're generating layout, the index can be passed in

```
func generateLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {(sectionIndex: Int, layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        // do your layout stuff here. With sectionIndex, you can layout differently for each section
    }
    return layout
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. Specifically inside the sectionProvider you need to conditionally assign the value of `NSCollectionLayoutSection.boundarySupplementaryItems`. I will suggest an edit to this answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

For now there seems like there is no other way to do it other than creating your own protocol for figuring out whether headers should be displayed in a section. Luckily, the `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` constructor gives us the section index so it's quite easy to do. Simply do not create any supplementary views for a section without them.

```
protocol CollectionViewLayoutProviderDelegate: class {
    func layoutProvider(_ provider: CollectionViewLayoutProvider, shouldDisplaySupplementaryViewIn section: Int) -> Bool
}

class CollectionViewLayoutProvider {
    weak var delegate: CollectionViewLayoutProviderDelegate?
    init(delegate: CollectionViewLayoutProviderDelegate?) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
    
    private func prepareSupplementaryViews(section: Int) -> [NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem] {
        if let delegate = delegate,
           !delegate.layoutProvider(self, shouldDisplaySupplementaryViewIn: section) {
// Return empty array to avoid displaying headers

            return []
        }
        // Configure header if you need to
    }
    
    private func prepareSection(section: Int, group: NSCollectionLayoutGroup) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        layoutSection.boundarySupplementaryItems = prepareSupplementaryViews(section: section)
        
        return layoutSection
    }
}
```

Then, in your view controller

```
private lazy var layoutProvider = CollectionViewLayoutProvider(delegate: self)

extension YouViewController: CollectionViewLayoutProviderDelegate {
    func layoutProvider(_ provider: CollectionViewLayoutProvider, shouldDisplaySupplementaryViewIn section: Int) -> Bool {
        return viewModel.shouldDisplayHeader(for: section) != nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func configureDiffableDataSource() {
    let dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<TripSection, TripItem>(collectionView: collectionView) {
        (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, item: TripItem) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueCell(ofType: SmallTableViewCell.self, for: indexPath)
      cell.fillWithData(tip)
       return cell
        }
    }
```

//ADD elementKindSectionHeader return nil if isFullScreen

```
    dataSource.supplementaryViewProvider = { [weak self] (collectionView: UICollectionView, kind: String, indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView? iln
        guard let itamSequence = self?.dataSource?.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) else { return nil }
        guard let section = self?.dataSource?.snapshot().sectionIdentifier(containingItem: itamSequence) else { return nil }
       let boardHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableView(ofType: BoardSupplementaryView.self, forKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, for: indexPath)
         return boardHeader
        }
    }

     self.dataSource = dataSource
     updateSnapshot(animated: false)
}
```

Comment: how do you force rebuilding data source ?

Comment: This is what I'm wondering, how do I rebuild it after the condition is met?  Any ideas @Markon?

Comment: not sure what you mean, what condition?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`, you can hide the footer like this:

```
/// Hides the footer of the collectionView (animated)
func hideFooter() {
    let compLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        compLayout?.configuration = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
    }
}
```

Prerequisite (you need to set the footer like this):

```
let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { ... }
let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
let size = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
    heightDimension: .estimated(10))
let footer = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(
    layoutSize: size,
    elementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter,
    alignment: .bottom, absoluteOffset: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
config.boundarySupplementaryItems = [footer]
layout.configuration = config
```